# Collecting unique elements during Spark aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, append

#### Problem

I need to update this line in my code. How do I do that?

```
"case StringType => concat_ws(",",collect_list(col(c)))"
```

To only append strings that are not already in the existing field. In this example, the letter "b" would not appear twice.

#### Code

```
val df =Seq(
     (1, 1.0, true, "a"),
     (2, 2.0, false, "b")
     (3, 2.0, false, "b")
     (3, 2.0, false, "c")
).toDF("id","d","b","s")

val dataTypes: Map[String, DataType] = df.schema.map(sf => 
(sf.name,sf.dataType)).toMap

def genericAgg(c:String) = {
  dataTypes(c) match {
  case DoubleType => sum(col(c))
  case StringType => concat_ws(",",collect_list(col(c)))
  case BooleanType => max(col(c))
  }
}

val aggExprs: Seq[Column] = df.columns.filterNot(_=="id")
.map(c => genericAgg(c))

df
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(
    aggExprs.head,aggExprs.tail:_*
  )
  .show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `collect_set()` instead of `collect_list()`. This will automatically remove duplicates during the collection.

I am not sure why you want to turn the array of unique strings into a comma-delimited list. Spark can easily handle array columns and they are displayed such that each element can be seen. Still, if you absolutely must have the array converted into a comma-delimited string, use [`array_join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#array_join) in Spark 2.4+ or a UDF in earlier versions of Spark.

Comment: How can I add a column to this code
"df.groupBy("id").agg(aggExprs.head,aggExprs.tail:_*)"
that simply gives me the count on the tuple being group. (e.g "select id, d, COUNT(*) from tbl group by id, d").
Thank You!!